# MySql: Operate on Many Rows Using Long List of Composite PKs

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, list, large-data-volumes, set-based

What's a good way to work with many rows in MySql, given that I have a long list of keys in a client application that is connecting with ODBC?

Note: my experience is largely SQL Server, so I know a bit, just not MySQL specifically.

The task is to delete some rows from 9 tables, but I might have upwards of 5,000 key pairs.

I started out with the easy way of looping through all my keys and submitting a statement for each one against each table, such as:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Key1 = 123 AND Key2 = 567 -- and 8 more tables
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Key1 = 124 AND Key2 = 568 -- and 8 more tables
DELETE FROM Table WHERE Key1 = 125 AND Key2 = 569 -- and 8 more tables
...
```

Except, that comes out to 45,000 separate statements, which as you can imagine is a bit slow.

So, without worrying about the programming language I'm using on the front end, what's a good way to submit the list so that I can JOIN and do the operation all at once or at least in large batches? Here are my ideas so far:

- Create a **temp table** and insert to it, then join. I'll happily look up the syntax for MySQL to create a temp table, but is that a good route to go?
- Assuming I do use a temp table, what's the best **method for populating a temp table**? 5000 `INSERT Table VALUES ()` statements? `SELECT 123, 456 UNION ALL SELECT 124, 457`? I just tested that MySql allows this kind of SELECT that is not issued against a table. But SQL Server eventually blows up if the list gets too long, so is this a good way in MySQL? Should I just keep the list to a few hundred at once?

  ```
  --CREATE Temp Table ( I do not know the syntax in MySql yet)

  INSERT INTO TempTable
  SELECT 123, 456
  UNION ALL SELECT 124, 457
  UNION ALL SELECT 125, 458

  DELETE T
  FROM
     Table T
     INNER JOIN TempTable X ON T.Key1 = X.Key1 AND T.Key2 = X.Key2
  ```
- **XML**. I see MySQL 5.1 has some XML functions, but from a cursory search it doesn't appear to support turning a chunk of XML text into a rowset to join against. Is that true? It is extremely easy for me to get the values into XML.
- A virtual **split operation**. I presume in MySql that there's some kind of procedural language possible. In SQL Server I could write some custom code that parses a string and turns it into a rowset:

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE DoStuff @KeyString varchar(max)
  AS
  DECLARE @Keys TABLE (
     Key1 int,
     Key2 int,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Key1, Key2)
  )
  DECLARE @Pos int
  WHILE @Pos < Len(@KeyString) BEGIN
     -- loop to search for delimiting commas in @KeyString
     -- and insert pairs of parsed tokens to table variable @Keys
  END

  DELETE T
  FROM
     Table T
     INNER JOIN @Keys K ON T.Key1 = K.Key1 AND T.Key2 = K.Key2
  ```

Since I'm unfamiliar with MySQL, I really don't know which possibility to investigate first, and I would appreciate some help to save me from making a poor decision and/or learning the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the temp table solution, and join it to each main table in the `DELETE` statements.  So you only have to do nine deletes, one for each table.

- [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

  ```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Keys (
      Key1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
      Key2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY(Key1, Key2)
  );
  ```
- Load a file of tab-separated data into the temp table using [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

  ```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/path/to/datafile' INTO TABLE Keys;
  ```
- Delete using MySQL's multi-table [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) syntax.

  ```
  DELETE t FROM Table1 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table2 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table3 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table4 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table5 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table6 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table7 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table8 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  DELETE t FROM Table9 t JOIN Keys USING (Key1, Key2);
  ```

---

Re your comment:

The MySQL docs on `CREATE TABLE` say the following:

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY  table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)

That's pretty clear!

Regarding loading the data, you could just do it with `INSERT`.  5000 rows is no big deal.  I use a PHP script to load *millions* of rows (e.g. the StackOverflow XML data dump) into MySQL and that only takes about 20 minutes.  I use a prepared statement and then execute it with parameters.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this looks like dynamite. I will look into the LOAD DATA method, though I'm not sure that I'll be able to write to such a file easily. Is there another script way to load the temp table? Also, could you elaborate just a little on the scope of temp tables (what happens if two sessions try to create a temp table with the same name, or the name already exists as a real table, and is the temp table destroyed when the connection closes)?

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote. Thank you for the depth and detail of your answer. I admit I could have gone and researched all of these things (and I plan to do it still) but a nice round answer is so great.

Comment: I wish you could too, because your upvote brought me to 44,999!  :-)  Cheers!